# Highchart Container, Download Issue at Live Server

Tags: javascript, highcharts, download

I have integrated highchart type "Container", while customise tooltip for additional informations. Its working perfectly both render and download at local machine, but I am facing download issue when deployed it at live server. Its rendering perfectly at live server.

Everytime I click to Download "PNG or Jpeg or PDF": I am getting this error **"error when performing chart generation: please check your input data"** while URL redirect from my website to "https://export.highcharts.com/".

I am scratching my head for last hour but unable to get satisfactory answer/solution.. Why its working fine at local and why not at live. I have grant all permissions to all files at live.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste your chart configuration here and test on http://export.highcharts.com/ ?